# Wrap a div around every iframe

Tags: php, html

I want to wrap a div around every iframe automatically with one piece of php code. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

I'm using a CMS where users can add embedded youtube videos, but the videos are not responsive on my website. So I want to make them responsive, that's why have to add a div around every iframe.

The output I need is:

```
<div class="generated-div">
    <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/23523wsfw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not too complicated, you can use `str_replace()` method

```
$new = str_replace(['<iframe', '</iframe>'], ['<div class="generated-div"><iframe', '</iframe></div>'], $str);
```

Comment: Very simple answer, and exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create div tag at runtime, then you go for Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/23523wsfw");
ifrm.style.width = "640px";
ifrm.style.height = "360px";
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = 'generated-div';
divTag.className = 'generated-div';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divTag);
divTag.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
```